# C++17 polymorphic memory recources not working

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17

I was trying to understand the c++17 pmr.
So I did this and it is not working as I thought, what could go wrong?

```
template <typename T>
class Memory : public std::experimental::pmr::memory_resource {
  public:
    Memory() { this->memory = allocate(sizeof(T), alignof(T)); }
    void *getMemory() { return this->memory; }

    ~Memory() { deallocate(this->memory, sizeof(T), alignof(T)); }

  private:
    void *do_allocate(std::size_t bytes, std::size_t alignment)
    {
        memory = ::operator new(bytes);
    }
    void do_deallocate(void *p, std::size_t bytes, std::size_t alignment)
    {
        ::operator delete(memory);
    }
    bool do_is_equal(
           const std::experimental::pmr::memory_resource& other) const noexcept
    {
    }
    void *memory;
};
```

what can be going wrong with my implementation?
This is the client..

```
Memory<std::string> mem;
std::string * st = (std::string*)mem.getMemory();
st->assign("Pius");
std::cout << *st;
```

Comment: You must construct objects! Providing storage for them is not sufficient.

Comment: Change the definition of `st` to use placement new: `std::string* st = new (mem.getMemory()) std::string();` This will construct a `string` object at the memory provided by `mem.getMemory()`.

Comment: Please turn your compiler warnings up. Tell the compiler to treat warnings as errors. This will give you a couple of things to fix of the bat. Casting one type to another should be a red flag.

Answer (score 1):

The polymorphic resource allocators allocate *memory*; that's all they do. Unlike container Allocators, they don't create *objects*. That's why they return `void*`s.

Memory resources are not meant to be used by themselves. That's why `std::polymorphic_allocator<T>` exists. You can also do the object creation/destruction yourself, using placement-`new` and manual destructor calls.

Also, your memory_resource implementation makes no sense. `do_allocate` should *return* the allocated memory, not store it internally. Your function provokes undefined behavior by returning nothing (which your compiler should have warned about).